# Changing title of compiled/compressed EXE

Tags: c++, windows, exe

I would like to change the title of an existing exe file that has no source code. It can be done with a title changer application but I wish it to be permanent.

This is a re-post as My previous question was a bit vague, please don't thumbs down my question as I am new to programming but can't find anywhere else to ask.

Comment: Search for the string inside in the binary and change it is the simplest way (for a non-obfuscated program), just that the length of the new string must be <= the current string.

Comment: Note that is might be against the EULA of your product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, you may be able to use a binary editor to search the executable for the title bar text. You could then change the characters to whatever you want, as long as the number of characters is **exactly the same** (if it changes, you could screw up the file layout and bad things could happen, depending on how/where the text is stored).

It's entirely possible that it won't work though. For example, it's quite common for programs to modify the title bar text programmatically, adding the name of the currently open file or similar. In such cases, it will probably be impossible to modify the binary correctly without some major reverse engineering.

It's also important to be aware that changing anything in the binary could have unexpected side effects. For example, the same string could be used by some other part of the program, in which case you'll unavoidably change that too.

Comment: Why would it need to have the same size? Wouldn't it be ok if the new string it equal or smaller in size?

Comment: @typ1232: It depends on how and where it's stored. If you change the size, it means everything after it in the file is moved. That would potentially invalidate byte offsets.

Comment: Yes, sure you need to preserve size. But you can easily do that with for example replacing "hello" with "abc\0\0". Every c-string function in the executable will then only process "abc".

Comment: I think that may be the problem I am having then, There is no string to edit so it must have been programmatically changed. :/ it's a real shame, it has taken so much time, I should have asked before I tried everything. Thanks for the well constructed answer, if this were

Comment: you, would you do anything next? or just leave it at that?

Comment: @typ1232: Yes, padding with nulls to preserve the overall number of characters should usually work. Not all strings are null-terminated though, so in theory there could be some side effects from having nulls within a string, but usually nothing serious.

Comment: @MoltenVidia: I'm sorry I can't really recommend anything else. You might have some luck with reverse engineering, but that's easier said than done.

Comment: If you know the program always ultimately uses a specific function like `SetWindowText` to set the title, you could make your own custom version of this function (which would presumably supply a custom title) and then cause the program to use your version of this function via LD_PRELOAD (Linux) or DLL Injection (Windows). This is probably overkill but maybe more tenable than reverse engineering the program in question.

Comment: Hmm I don't know how the program was constructed, but the guy who did it was a smart man so it may be a long shot. I thought I could overwrite the set title code with a dll using of some sort using ollydbg but I guess that's easier said than done. (especially in my case)

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, just one last question as it probably won't be good for a new thread. What would you recommend me reading to learn programming. I want to learn C++ and Java(not javascript) and am currently reading C++ primer and finding it good so far. I would also like to understand the fundamentals such as how the computer actually understands code, and how hex code plays a part, you know stuff like that. Thanks again

Comment: @MoltenVidia For the second question I would recommend compiling C (because it is usually simpler) and looking at the generated assembly. See how each hex code corresponds to a given instruction,

Comment: Thanks thats what I will try, I will make a simple C++ calculator and see what the hex code is for  that :)

Answer (score 2):

If the title is stored as a resource inside the executable, you should be able to use any resource editor to change it, e.g. [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the input but im afraid it can't be done in my case :/ wish it were that easy myself. I would 1 up you if I had the rep haha